# Wordpress REST API: Query media files attached to a custom post type

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, rest-api

I want to attach an React native app to a Wordpress E-Learning Portal (leveraging the LearnPress-Plugin) to authenticate enrolled students and download audio assets of the course to the app.

The Plugin uses custom post types for courses & lessons.

So after authentication I use the Media Query to retreive the audio assets via [Rest Media API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/#arguments)

I want to retreive all media assets attached to a certain lesson Id, so I use the `parent` argument in the query:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/media/?media_type=audio&parent={LESSON_POST_ID}
```

I get empty results.

If I attach the media files to a regular wordpress post, the query works fine

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/media/?media_type=audio&parent={SOME_REGULAR_POST_ID}
```

So I guess the problem is that the lessons are custom post types?!

Do you have any solution or any workaround for this?

I could attach all needed media files to a regular post and query for them, but then I need to hardcode the post-id into the app, which I would like to avoid.

Thank you in advance!

### Additional info

I attach the media items via AdminPanel->Media
[image]

This leads to an insert of the corresponding post_parent Id in the DB.
[image]

Comment: How are you attaching the media to the custom post? Just be aware that merely using an image in a post does not necessarily “attach” it. That only happens when you upload it for the first time to a post.

Comment: I attach them via admin panel -> media ->"Attach" ("Uploaded to" table column) I've added screenshots to the post

Comment: If you retrieve from `/wp-json/wp/v2/media/?media_type=audio` (i.e. only the `media_type` parameter specified), do you see the audio in question in the media list? Are you sure you used the correct lesson post ID? And in the DB screenshot, I could see 3 audio attachments, so if the parent post for those audios are lesson posts, then try using the 191/12/13, e.g. `parent=191`?